# testing equality when there's a mutable inside an immutable.js structure

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Testing equality is pretty easy when everything is immutable:

```
a = Map({foo: 1});
b = Map({foo: 1});
is(a,b) //true
```

Now, let's put a mutable structure inside:

```
a = Map({foo:{bar: 1}});
b = Map({foo:{bar: 1}});
is(a,b) //false
```

Dang! So what's the *cleanest* way to accomplish this? (yeah, yeah, I know mutables inside an immutable is sick & wrong, but I can't control what folks put inside my structures)

A couple ideas:

- Use `toJS` and deepEqual the native objects. I don't really like this since I lose a lot of control over things like item order, etc.
- Recursively use `fromJS` I like this, I think it's probably the best approach, but assuming I don't know the shape of the mutable, I can't figure out how to do it in only a line or 2. Code examples welcomed!
- ???

Comment: Could you elaborate on this point? 

"I don't really like this since I lose a lot of control over things like item order, etc."

Comment: sure, it's because `toJS` converts to a native `Object`, not a native `Map`. For example, `a = new Map([['foo', 1],['bar,2']])` is different from `b = new Map([['bar', 2],['foo,1']])` and should throw false, but converted to an `Object` returns true, since order doesn't matter

Comment: which libraries are you using to test?